# Mysql NOT not working in this query using GROUP BY - why?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Strange wording "`Not` not working!" I know, but strangely enough results are being returned where `user_id` does exist, though the query directs `NOT (user_id = 1)`.

```
SELECT post_id, last_update
       FROM the_table
       WHERE last_update
       BETWEEN NOW( ) - INTERVAL 7 DAY 
       AND NOW( ) AND NOT (user_id =1)
       GROUP BY post_id
       ORDER BY last_update DESC
```

Simply stated, we're trying to retrieve the latest results the user hasn't voted on - but results are turning up where the user has indeed voted despite the `NOT (user_id = 1)`.
How is this possible? Is one one part of the query over-riding another? Perhaps the grouping?

Oddly enough, things work as predicted on Localhost, but not on the server! Its as though there is a tear in the sql-continuum and reality changes depending on environment. (And yes, user_id is 1 on both server and localhost)

Comment: Have you tried changing it to AND (user_id != 1)

Comment: Try `AND user_id != 1`. Could you post some data of your database?

Comment: Why the `NOT(user_id=1)` thing? Seems like a strange way to do it...

Comment: The fact that it works on localhost is fluke. The results of this kind of query (specifically, the abuse of the GROUP BY clause) is inherently *un*predictable.

Comment: "abuse" of the group by clause??? How is this being abused Isn't it a function as any other for this sort of purpose? Still thanks because it appears it is unpredictable. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: Curious - why are all the answers being downvoted? Seem like reasonable options to me...

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. I'm getting ready to accept one of them once the timer allows me to.

Comment: @Orangeman555 Others will argue, but in the absence of any aggregating functions, I consider the use of this clause inappropriate - and potentially misleading. And no. It's not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM the_table x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT post_id
            , user_id
            , MAX(last_update) max_last_update
         FROM the_table
        WHERE last_update BETWEEN NOW( ) - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND NOW( ) 
          AND user_id <> 1
        GROUP
           BY post_id
            , user_id
     ) y
    ON y.post_id = x.post_id
   AND y.user_id = x.user_id
   AND y.max_last_update = x.last_update
 ORDER   
    BY x.last_update DESC;
```

Comment: Your an SQL wizard. That works. My use of "group by" was killing it for some reason. This works.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm no wizard - this is standard stuff!